# Get the nearest N coordinates?

Tags: javascript, geometry

[image: envelope]

Given a set of coordinates `[x,y][]`. For example, `[[0,0], [5,10]....]`, how do I find the nearest N coordinates given a point? `nearest(point, coordinates, N)`

The idea is to do some geometric analysis.

```
const coordinates = [[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [50,50], [65, 50]]

function distance(p, q) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(q[0] - p[0], 2) + Math.pow(q[1] - p[1], 2))
}

function nearestNCoordinates(point, points, n) {
  const closestNCoordinates = []
  let cur = point

  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    const closest = points.filter(point => point[0] != cur[0] && point[1] != cur[1]).reduce((a, b) => distance(a, cur) < distance(b, cur) ? a : b);
    console.log(cur, closest)
    cur = closest
    closestNCoordinates.push(closest)
  } 
  
  return closestNCoordinates
}
```

My current code doesn't really work. It returns replicate datapoints and the result is not accurate.

For example, `nearestNCoordinates([0,0], coordinates, 3)` will return `[[50,50], [0,2], [50,50]]`, but I expect `[[0,1], [0,2], [50,50]]` because based on the distances. Those 3 points are closest to [0,0].

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example. what `x`, `y` are you testing for? Have you done any debugging to determine why it's returning duplicates?

Comment: What happens when you call `[0,0], coordinates, 3)`? What is your expected answer

Comment: `points.filter(point => point[0] != cur[0] && point[1] != cur[1])` You're filtering out any x-y pair that has the same x or y as the original point, so of course `[0,1]` and `[0,2]` won't be in your result.

Comment: It's also confusing that you pass `point` to `nearestNCoordinations()` and use `point` in your `filter()`.

Comment: @user1599011 If I don't filter, it will always return `[0,0]`. So the result is `[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]`

Comment: Maybe remove that coordinate from `points` before you start checking distances.

Comment: Because I need to get N points, it needs to also filter the last result. Otherwise the loop always returns the same coordinate

Comment: If one of the coordinates in your filter  matches the original, it'll be filtered out. Try `||` instead of `&&`.